# Changing nodes icon and clickable area in Google Maps Drawing Library (polygon)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, drawing, google-maps-markers

As you know, Google Maps Drawing Library is easy to implement, but it gives very little control to the developer.
(Here is a sample of the library at use http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html )

I would like to change the default settings of drawing polygons in two ways:

- first, I'd like to use another icon for the nodes connecting lines instead of the small square icon
- second, I like to increase the clickable area around the initial node.

Do you know if it's possible to do these changes to the drawing library?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with the existing drawing manager functionality. Please go through the following issue in Google maps api issues

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=drawing%20library&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=3760